# how to sort on a string date on a collection of objects

Tags: java, list, sorting, arraylist

So I'm having trouble remembering the syntax. I have an List of objects I'm trying to sort based on the value of date. The object looks like this.

```
Public class someobject{
    private String author;
    private String createDate;
    private String subject;
    private String body;
    private String claimNumber;
    private String authoringDate;
}
```

I'm trying to sort on the createDate value. Something like

```
List<someObject> someObjectList = new ArrayList<>();

someObjectList.sort()
```

currently the way the strings are arriving for the createDate object is YYYY/MM/DD.

Comment: Won't it work if you treat it as string which it is? 2011/12/31 will be earlier than 2012/12/31.

Comment: `someObjectList.sort(Comparator.comparing(someobject::getCreateDate));`

Comment: @MuhammadGulfam Currently it is a string, this is legacy code, but I need to sort this list based on that date. I'm sure theres a stream where I could convert it to a datetime then sort based on that.

Comment: Best solution is to store that value as a `LocalDate` rather than String.

Answer (score 1):

Dates in the format `YYYY/MM/DD` may be correctly sorted as strings, ie lexicographically, so:

```
someObjectList.sort(Comparator.comparing(someobject::getCreateDate));
```

or, if you don't have a getter method for `createDate`:

```
someObjectList.sort(Comparator.comparing(o -> o.createDate));
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting the correct comparing result you have to convert String value from the field "creationDate" to Date or LocalDate than you have to make Comparator for instance like that:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY/MM/DD");
someObjectList.sort(Comparator.comparingLong(ob -> formatter.parse(ob.createDate).get(ChronoField.EPOCH_DAY)));
```

or

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY/MM/DD");
someObjectList.sort(Comparator.comparingLong(ob -> LocalDate.parse(ob.createDate, formatter).atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toEpochSecond()));
```